# I am trying to rewrite urls in Wordpress, but its not working

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'us-dot-numbers/([0-9]+)/?',
        'index.php/?page_id=642&dotNumber=80806',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'dotNumber';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

I am using this code in function.php . I am using flushing function to flush rewrite rules.

I want to redirect www.domain.com/us-dot-numbers/80806 to point to www.domain.com/index.php/?page_id=642&dotNumber=80806

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong. Also please let me know the regex for "Alphabets, Numbers and hyphen only",

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init', 10, 0);
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^us-dot-numbers/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?',
        'index.php?page_id=642&dotNumber=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'dotNumber';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Remember to `flush_rewrite_rules();`

Comment: Hello, @Drupalizeme Thanks for your response, its redirecting to the page_id=642 but when i do a print_r of the $_GET variable, it gives be a blank Array so i am not able to get data from there ,Please help.other wise its going to the page i want it to go. Thanks.

Comment: Try get it with `get_query_var('dotNumber);` or `$dotNumber`